# Disable Exit Full screen functionality using JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to override F11 key to toggle some modal window.

```
$(window).on('keydown', handleKeyEvents);

function handleKeyEvents (e) {
    if(e.which == 122) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Override here");
    }
}
```

This code works fine if window is not in Full Screen mode. But If the window is in Full screen mode and on pressing F11 key, the handleKeyEvents function is not getting fired, whereas browser exiting the full screen mode.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zr1ym74d/

Note: I don't want to use any third party library.

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781080/keydown-event-not-fired-when-pressing-escape-in-fullscreen-in-chrome-firefox) helps!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keydown event not fired when pressing escape in fullscreen in Chrome/Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781080/keydown-event-not-fired-when-pressing-escape-in-fullscreen-in-chrome-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer but as a plausible guess, I'd say the browser is reserving the F11 key handler in full screen to prevent people from blocking exiting fullscreen.